# How to resolve "413 Request Entity Too Large nginx/1.1.19" error?

Tags: php, laravel, apache, nginx, apache2

When I'm trying to upload a file on my apache2, Laravel server I get this error:

413 Request Entity Too Large

---

nginx/1.1.19

Which of course means my file is too large.

But I changed php.ini

max_file_uploads 20

post_max_size 20M

upload_max_filesize 25M

& sites-available/site.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName site

DocumentRoot /var/www/site/public

<Directory /var/www/site/public/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
        Require all granted
</Directory>

ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/site-error.log
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/site-access.log combined

LimitRequestBody 20000000
```

and sudo service apache2 restart

but error still having.

/etc/nginx/nginx.conf

or

/usr/local/nginx/conf/nginx.conf

not exists

Comment: probably nginx config > client_max_body_size  ?
The error itself seems nginx not PHP..

Comment: How big is the file you want to upload?

Comment: @DefinitelynotRafal
2.5M

Comment: @Svetoslav
Yes but can't find any nginx.conf file to change client_max_body_size

Comment: @Svetoslav
It shows me error 
413 Request Entity Too Large

nginx/1.1.19

Comment: You're uploading *to Apache httpd*, and get an *nginx error message*? Please clarify! I don't see any proxy configuration. When you edit: Make sure to hit stackoverflow's focus on programming topics (see [help/on-topic]) as configuration problems are off-topic.

Answer (score 0):

First run this command and find the config file path

```
nginx -t
```

And then add this like to it

```
client_max_body_size 200M;
```

(you can change the 200 to any number that you want) 
And then restart your nginx

Comment: I'm using apache2